# Django not found in remote API (but works in app!)

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

See source below. The app I deployed using:

```
gcloud app deploy
```

Django templating works fine, as seen when loading:

```
https://myapp.appspot.com/foo.txt
```

When connecting to the remote API, however, I get an error:

```
C:\myapp>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\remote_api_shell.py" myapp
App Engine remote_api shell
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:03:49) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
The db, ndb, users, urlfetch, and memcache modules are imported.
s~myapp> from main import Foo
WARNING:root:You are using the default Django version (0.96). The default Django version will change in an App Engine release in the near future. Please call use_library() to explicitly select a Django version. For more information see https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries#Django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\template.py", line 63, in <module>
    webapp._config_handle.django_setup()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\__init__.py", line 176, in _django_setup
    import django
ImportError: No module named django
s~myapp>
```

With Python 2.5 this issue did not exist. I could successfully connect to the remote API, import classes from `main.py` and populate the datastore. However, Python 2.5 is [being shut down](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/deprecations/python25) on GAE.

*Why does Django work for the app but not for the remote API? What needs to be changed?*

Source:

- `app.yaml`:

  ```
  runtime: python27
  api_version: 1
  threadsafe: false
  builtins:
  - remote_api: on
  handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: main.py
  ```
- `foo.txt`:

  ```
  Host: '{{ host }}'
  ```
- `main.py`:

  ```
  import os
  import google.appengine.ext.db
  from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
  from google.appengine.ext import webapp
  from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
  from google.appengine.ext import db

  class Foo(db.Model):
      bar = db.IntegerProperty()

  class FooTxt(webapp.RequestHandler):
      def get(self):
          template_values = {
              'host': self.request.host
              }

          path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'foo.txt')
          self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'
          self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))

  application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/foo.txt', FooTxt)], debug = False)

  def main():
      run_wsgi_app(application)

  if __name__ == "__main__":
      main()
  ```